# Changing themes in Grails 3.x.x

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I couldn't find a single blog in google to update themes plugin for Grails 3.x.x.
If anyone familiar in playing with themes using gradle properties file that comes with Grails 3.x.x project, please let me know...

I have been struggling with Gradle after upgrading to 3.x.x version

I tried the following and ended up with failure....

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ....   
    compile "org.grails.plugins:platform-ui:1.0.RC7"
    .....
}
```

|

> Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
>
> CONFIGURE FAILED
>
> Total time: 13.404 secs Error | Error initializing classpath: Could
>   not find org.grails.plugins:platform-ui:1.0.RC7. Searched in the
>   following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.jar
>       https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.pom
>       https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.jar
>   Required by:
>       project : (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'apprater'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
>   >     Could not find org.grails.plugins:platform-ui:1.0.RC7.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.jar
>   >          https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.pom
>   >          https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/platform-ui/1.0.RC7/platform-ui-1.0.RC7.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Could you clarify what your asking? Are you using a plugin called themes? (I don't see one called that in the grails2 plugin portal)

Comment: No no... how do I change my default theme in Grails 3... ?

Comment: Like changing to Twitter bootstrap

Comment: The author of the `platform-ui` plugin has not released a Grails 3 version - that is why you can't resolve it.

Comment: I think your answer was right. I think that was what I was looking for. Why did you delete it :). Please put it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later versions of Grails 2 and Grails 3 use asset-pipeline to process your css/javascript. By default Grails 3 does have a version of bootstrap under `grails-app/assets/stylesheets/*` but you in no way required to use it. You can customize it or remove it and add your own style sheets in. Then in your gsp/html reference those styles.

http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/

If you are looking to have your gradle project pull in javascript or stylesheet dependencies, take a look at the client dependencies gradle plugin https://github.com/craigburke/client-dependencies-gradle

Edit: 
Your question was updated with more information about the plugin you were using - it looks like the author of the `platform-ui` plugin has not released a Grails 3 plugin, so that is why you can't resolve the dependency.